# Can I grow a mini-sized date plant from a fresh seed?

Tags: containers, seeds, germination, bonsai

Is it possible to create a plant from a fresh date seed in a mini pot? When I say "mini" I mean a pot with diameter of maybe 6cm, like this one? (see image below)

I already tried this 3 times with 3 seeds that had roots coming out of each, but they all died. So, I'm wondering if the issue is with me, possibly inappropriate soil or a too small pot, or it's just not possible to make it grow as a mini plant.

The soil I'm using is a mix of:

- 1/3 vermiculite
- zeolite
- organic soil

[image]

Comment: Hi Dani! I re-worded your title a bit to match our usual format. Also, your last paragraph asked if it might not be possible to grow it as a "meme" plant. I looked up that term and couldn't find anything, so I substituted the word "mini" as it seemed to make sense. If it was meant to be "meme" instead, I apologize, and hope you'll go back and fix it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid bonsai for [monocotyledons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monocotyledon) are very difficult if not impossible. But I am not sure if that's what you mean with meme plant? Palms, such as the [Date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_palm) palm, are not really trees (as real bonsai are) and therefore the techniques applied to bonsai do not work here.

The seed would in theory be able to germinate in a small pot, but would need a bigger pot as soon the plant starts to grow. Date seeds should germinate well in just normal potting soil (kept a bit wet and warm). It could take a few weeks to months though.

So making a miniature palm in a 6 cm diameter pot is according to my knowledge and experience not feasible.